# Inject variable from the views to my angular controller?

Tags: django, angularjs

I'm trying to create a website with articles. I have a page that displays a list of all the articles, and I try to do one that displays the detail of an article. I use angular.js to get the json of my datas. I don't have any problem to get the list of my articles since I only need to do :

```
function ArticleListCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/articles/?format=json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.articles = data;
    });
}
```

But now I only want to access for example the article with id 4. How do I do that ? Is there a way to inject the primary key entered in the url into the javascript ? I'm new to angular, and I'm pretty sure there is an easy way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you need is to define a partial template and a route,
for the detail view of your article.

An example is [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07)

More specifically what you'd need is something like the following.

```
angular.module('myapp', []).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when('/articles/:articleId', {templateUrl: 'partials/article-detail.html', controller: ArticleDetailCtrl}).
      otherwise({redirectTo: '/articles'});
}]);
```

What the above does, is to hijack urls of the form `/articles/5/` and instead of actually
performing that `GET` request to your server, it will just ask for `partials/article-detail.html`. This of course will be your article detail template, which will be handled
by your ArticleDetailCrtl controller.

In your ArticleDetailCrtl controller function, don't forget to include the [$routeParams](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24routeParams)
service. This will give you access to the url parameters, such as `articleId`, which we
defined above.

The final thing to do is to generate these links in your article list template. e.g:

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="article in articles"><a href="/articles/{{article.id}}/">{{article.title}}</a>
</ul>
```

Comment: @ThomasPdobear For completion, I updated my answer to include the `routeParams` service, that you will probably need.

Comment: Just a quick question, how do I type the param from routeParams into my $http.get ? I can't do `$http.get('/tasks/$routeParams.articleId/format=json').success(function(data) { ... }`

Comment: @ThomasPdobear right now you have `$routeParams` inside a string.

Comment: Yup, but I'd like to use this $routeParams inside a string, how could I go ? Like, I'd like to get the /tasks/2/?format=json where 2 is my $routeParams

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31526/discussion-between-rantanplan-and-thomas-pdobear)